# Exception for classes I/O

Tags: java, exception, io, ioexception

I'm studying for OCP exam these classes I/O:

- OutputStream subclasses:

  - FileOutputStream
  - BufferedOutputStream
  - DataOutputStream
  - PrintStream (I see its methods  write() don't throw exceptions)
- Writer subclasses:

  - FileWriter
  - BufferedWriter
  - PrintWriter (I see its methods write() don't throw exceptions)
- Reader subclasses:

  - FileReader
  - BufferedReader
- InputStream subclasses:

  - BufferedInputStream
  - FilterInputStream
  - ObjectInputStream

My question:
For the main methods read and write (with different signatures), when does each of these classes throw the IOException? In the javadoc there is only a phrase:

> IOException - if an I/O error occurs

without an explanation about the cases.

I know this (I don't know if these are correct):

- FileOutputStream throws java.io.FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist. This class, infact, doesn't create a file;
- FileWriter throws java.io.FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist. This class infact, doesn't create a file;
- BufferedReader throws java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException (subclass of IOException), if file doesn't exist;
- FileInputStream throws java.io.FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist.

Thanks a lot!

A.

Comment: Creating a FileWriter/OutputStream does create the file. It's vague on purpose: any IO problem will cause an IOException to be thrown. For example, if the file is being deleted while reading/writing. Or if the hard drive is damaged. Or if there is no space left to write, or the OS somehow refuses to read or write (because there is a network error on a network drive, or because there is a permission issue). It could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An I/O exception is thrown by any of these classes when they encounter a problem during execution. The file output streams can throw an exception if :

- File don't exist
- File is read only
- The OS refuses access to the file
- The drive you are writing to dose not have sufficient space

The input streams usually throws exception if :

- The stream is not properly initialised
- The input type is miss matched
- If the file beeing read from is changed while reading
- If the file doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want the specific exception class simply Google " What exception will be thrown by ______ when _____ "

Answer (score 1):

If you google the API documentation for the class, generally the Javadocs will give an explanation of what exceptions are thrown in what circumstances, e.g. for 
FileWriter

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html